# My IF statement is not working as it should, how do I fix this?

Tags: python

I am creating a quiz program that draws a question and answer from a .txt file. The questions and answers are in the format:

question,answer

in the .txt file. The program picks one at random, splits it at the comma and asks the question. It then matches the users answer to the questions answer and checks if it is correct like this:

```
if userAnswer == question[1]:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Incorrect, better luck next time!')
```

Every time I run the program I get no errors but no matter what I put, the program tells me I'm incorrect. I've asked a few friends but they are all as confused as me and none of us have any clue what the problem is.
The code the splits the question and answer:

```
f = open('Music.txt', 'r')
question = random.choice(list(f))
question = question.split(',')
userAnswer = input(f'Who sang {question[0]}? ').lower()
```

I should clarify, the .txt file questions are all songs and all the answers are bands/singers. None of the answers contain comma's.

Comment: Show us the code which reads the .txt file and splits. Also how does .txt file look like. Does you answer contains `,`? If yes then splitting with `,` will split the answer also. You can try printing `question[1]` and `userAnswer`.

Comment: The syntax of the statement is fine, so there is nothing we can help you with without more code. Obviously `userAnswer` is not equal to `question[1]`. Have you checked they are both in the same format? Is there any trailing whitespace (try `string.strip()`)?

Comment: The question and answer are on the same line and are pulled from the text file together, also, I have tried printing both variables after typing the correct answer, they match but I still get 'Incorrect'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that since you questions,answers are new line separated, the answer from you read from the file ends with '\n'.
In order to remove it, run: `answer = answer.rstrip()` and then compare it to the answer provided as the user input.

Comment: `answer.rstrip()` is a little simpler and more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I debug this kind of problem:

```py
import random
f = open('Music.txt', 'r')
question = random.choice(list(f))
question = question.split(',')
userAnswer = input(f'Who sang {question[0]}? ').lower()

print("userAnswer: {}".format(userAnswer))
print("{}\n".format([ord(i) for i in userAnswer]))
print("question[1]: {}".format(question[1]))
print("{}\n".format([ord(i) for i in question[1]]))
if userAnswer == question[1]:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Incorrect, better luck next time!')
```

The output is

```
python tmp.py
Who sang Sandstorm? darude
userAnswer: darude
[100, 97, 114, 117, 100, 101]

question[1]: darude

[100, 97, 114, 117, 100, 101, 10]

Incorrect, better luck next time!
```

So it turns out that you have an additional character in the question, that you don't have in the `userAnswer`.
`chr(10)` gives us `\n`.

To get rid of any starting or trailing whitespace, you can use `strip`.

> If the chars argument is not provided, all leading and trailing whitespaces are removed from the string.

If you change the comparison line to `if userAnswer == question[1].strip():`, it works as you expect.